# How do I implement the number of rounds in this C++ code?

Tags: c++, loops

```
int round;
int Starting_index;
int hop_count;

for( round = 0; round < gNumRounds; round++)
{
    Starting_index[round] = gPasswordHash[0+round*4] * 256 + gPasswordHash[1+round*4];
    hop_count [round] = gPasswordHash[2+round*4] * 256 + gPasswordHash[3+round*4];

    if(hop_count == 0) hop_count = 0xFFFF;
}
```

`gPasswordHash`, `gNumRounds` are both global variables. The place where I'm getting an error is with setting the `Starting_index[round]` and `hop_count[round]` inside the `for` loop.

There may be something wrong with my `Starting_index` and `hop_count` declarations, but I'm unsure what that is.

Comment: what errror????

Comment: `Starting_index[round]` What is this even supposed to be?

Comment: "expression must have pointer-to-object type"

Comment: `Starting_index` is an int. You can't access it with `[]` operator. What do you actually want to do? Operating a bit of `Starting_index`?

Comment: @DeiDei it's the starting index for the loop but gets changed with code later. It's part of an encryption program that goes goes for a number of rounds, gNumRounds

Comment: @DeiDei and `hop_count[round]`, too

Comment: @duckyPluck `Starting_index` and `hop_count` are single `int`s, not arrays, so you can't index into them with `[round]`.

Comment: @DeiDei Ok, I got it. Thanks a lot for the help! I was just overlooking something kind of obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare those variables as arrays, not single `int`.

```
int Starting_index[MAXROUNDS];
int hop_count[MAXROUNDS];
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting_index and hop_count aren't declared as arrays, they're currently only ints. You also should be declaring and defining round inside the for loop declaration instead of earlier: 'for (int round = 0; round < gNumRounds; round++)'.

And I don't really know what you mean by 'if (hop_count == 0) hop_count = 0xFFFF;'.